# Compiling opencv with python support error

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to install opencv with python support and I am facing with an issue which I cant help on.

When I configure the project with `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..` it configures and says python support present.

```
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.10)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a (ver 2.7.10)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When I try to `make` it, it fails at

```
[ 75%] Built target opencv_test_contrib
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It builds just fine without python support.

I did not understand what this error means / how to fix this as I dont have much experience with cmake. Any help to debug this is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried what the error text says, i.e, "recompile with -fPIC"?

Comment: I did not understand how to use -fPIC with cmake build system.

Comment: @upr Did you find a solution for this error?. I'm getting same error also

Comment: Did any of you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to recompile with the "-fPIC" flag. Some research pulls up the easy fix. Add to the command `-D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC`, so that your whole command is `cmake -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..`

Please let the rest of the internet know if this works or not.

Comment: Hi @Mark. even after adding the -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC to the cmake configure step, it still fails with same message. I think this is some issue specific to opencv

Comment: It might not be; my answer was a shot in the dark. I don't know for certain the C flag carried over to the compiling. Can you grep your output for fPIC?

Comment: I grepped for fpic in the release folder of cmake and here is the output http://pastebin.com/CZb1Hj5j . -fPIC is certainly carried over to the compiling

Comment: As file compiled is c++, flags are `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Try same with them.

Comment: Even with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, the issue remains